# Migrating Ti.app.Properties from ios

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

How can i access the access Ti.app.properties for ios users with ios sdk 3.5.1.GA without using the Ti sdk ? Are they stored in an plist file on th client? This is for migration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both iOS and Android store app properties in special files on the filesystem. Natively, iOS properties are known as NSUserDefaults, which are stored in .plist files in the application's library directory. Android stores them in standard xml text files at /data/data/com.domainname.appname/shared_prefs/titanium.xml. Titanium provides a uniform means to set and get app properties via the Titanium.App.Properties API.